# linux file comparison

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems

I want to compare two file in Linux but the comparison should not be based on line by line comparison and I want to dump the result to another file.
For example:

file1 is:

```
ABC
B
KLM
JAH
MONU
PANDA
```

file 2 is:

```
HELLO
PRETTI
ABC
B
LKMO
```

Now what I want is to get the difference between file 1 and file 2 content wise and not line by line basis.like (file1-file2) i.e. contents that are  in file 1 not in 2

difference file:

```
KLM
JAH
MONU
PANDA
```

I tried with `diff`, `comm` in Linux but it shows the results by line by line comparison

Comment: would the needleman-wunch algorithm be of any use? http://search.cpan.org/~vbar/Algorithm-NeedlemanWunsch-0.03/lib/Algorithm/NeedlemanWunsch.pm

Comment: To get a worthwhile response, you need to describe the exact algorithm that you want to use. Looking at your example, it appears that you're tokenizing on spaces, and ignoring content in file2 that doesn't appear in file1. But that's only a guess.

Comment: actually the contents of the file are separated by newline character and not by spaces.

Answer (score 5):

```
sort file1.txt file2.txt file2.txt | uniq -u
```

This sorts file1 and *twice* file2 in place. When filtering unique values, only the values that occur in file1 *only* will be reported

If file1.txt is allowed to repeat the same value, you might want to preprocess, making thins a little more complicated:

```
sort <(sort -u file1.txt) file2.txt file2.txt | uniq -u
```

Comment: can you explain me why file2 is sorted twice.can you explain what is happening internally.

Comment: @monucool: its not just sorted twice, it is _included_ twice. This makes sure that any line _only in file2_ will _not_ get reported (because it 'occurs' twice). Note that if `file2.txt` contains 10 lines, `sort file2.txt file2.txt` by definition returns 20 lines, and `sort file2.txt file2.txt | uniq -u` return **0 lines** by definition

Comment: In other words: because `uniq -u` is used to _suppress any line occurring twice in the input` including file2 twice is the cheap way of telling our command to _never report lines from file2_. The net result is that lines _occurring uniquely in file1_ are being reported.

Comment: This approach doesn't preserve the original ordering.

Comment: @IanTegebo Well, that wasn't a requirement. But you're right, I'd use a simple perl or python script if that were required

Comment: @sehe ...except that you don't have to write a script.  See my answer to this question, it can be done simply with comm/grep.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused, why doesn't `comm` work?

```
comm -23 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Using your example files, the above produces:

```
JAH
KLM
MONU
PANDA
```

Which is exactly the "file" you wanted, modulo ordering.  Now if you want them sorted as they appear in `file1`, that's another matter.  I'm assuming your issue was not having suppressed the second column and that's how you got your "line by line comparison", to wit:

```
$ comm -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
    HELLO
JAH
KLM
    LKMO
MONU
PANDA
    PRETTI
```

On the matter of producing the "difference file" with the original ordering:

```
$ comm -23 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)|grep -f - file1
KLM
JAH
MONU
PANDA
```

Comment: +1 for standard UNIX tools. +1 for the `grep -f` trick, which I've never used before. Makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

I infer from your exaple output that you want to compute the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) (also called *edit distance*) between the two files.

Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance):

> The Levenshtein distance can also be computed between two longer
>   strings, but the cost to compute it, which is roughly proportional to
>   the product of the two string lengths, makes this impractical.

So how big are your files?  And are you tracking characters or words?  For small files (small number of characters or words, as appropriate) you can write your own command-line Levenshtein distance tool.

Comment: i am tracking words.and the words are one below the other i.e arranged in just one column

Answer (score 0):

Does the order in which the lines appear matter? If the order doesn't matter, this has a really elegant solution in awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN { 
  while((getline<"file2.txt")>0) {
    eliminate[$0] = 1
  }
}
!($0 in eliminate) { print }' file1.txt
```